How to apply a texture in Gazebo Garden?
I'm trying to build my own world for Gazebo Garden, but I'm stuck with texture.
I've got one model, the floor. Here is my sdf :
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.10">
  <model name="floor">
    <pose>
      0 0 -0.001
      0 0 0
    </pose>

    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>7 4</size>
          </plane>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>model://merce/materials/scripts</uri>
            <uri>model://merce/materials/textures</uri>
            <name>linoleum</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>7 4</size>
          </plane>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
            <mu>1</mu>
            <mu2>1</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>

my material
material linoleum
{
  receive_shadows off
  technique
  {
    pass
    {
      texture_unit
      {
        texture linoleum.png
      }
    }
  }
}

my files
src/gz/
├── models
│   └── merce
│       ├── floor.sdf
│       └── materials
│           ├── scripts
│           │   └── floor.material
│           └── textures
│               ├── linoleum.jpg
│               ├── linoleum.png

my command gz sim src/gz/models/merce/floor.sdf
I have no error message, but the floor is black (visual/material in the gui show all color black).
I tried to use absolute path, different file formats (png, jpg).
I'm wondering how the material file is used. I suppose all materials are loaded then the string after "material" is used as a unique id.
I didn't find any other related question recent.
I'm using Gazebo Sim version 7.7.0.

I found here that Garden does not support 